# Texture over geometry nodes array

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes

I have a series of cubes generated by a "Point instance" geometry node over a simple grid.

[image]

The texture is assigned to the source cube (on the right).

How can I add some UV coordinates, so the texture is mapped over all the array of cubes?

[image]

---

Just to complement the context

I am using geometry nodes to animate the scale and position of the individual cubes. As I am new to geometry nodes, I do not know if I could scale another type of array the same way as geometry nodes. (

[image]

Probably the answer is using a different way to generate the array and after that changing the position of the meshes, but then I would need to figure out how to animate those :o)

A really primitive idea I have is to project a light with the texture over the animation... but that is a dumb idea.

Comment: Here is an idea, but probably not 100% what you are looking for https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EznsQxCg8Cg&ab_channel=Pixldg

Comment: Looks promising. I'll take a deeper look. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible using geometry nodes in Blender yet. It is probably possible in 3.0, but geometry nodes are going to have quite a lot of changes before it is released. It is, however, possible to do it with shader nodes in Blender 2.93, using this node setup:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I will study the setup.

Comment: It worked very nicely. Ty.